# What are those odd colors in gitlab diff?

Tags: gitlab

[image: Diff example for gitlab]

I Gitlab, when diff is shown, some characters are show with unusual colors (.e.g. first line on the image, where symbol `<` is show as dark red on beige background in the line which does not have any changes). The same for '>=' and '.', which are red even in green (added) lines.

What is this? Bug? Feature?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is the open [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16683). According to examples from the comments it looks like highlighter marks some characters additionally with red depending on the file extension. There is no information in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/changes.html) about this behavior, so it appears to be a bug.